# How can I move all PRs from one repository to another?

Tags: git, github

I need to move the repository from one server to another. I'm looking forward to keeping the entire history including the PRs, however, I haven't figured out how to migrate the PRs yet. Anyone can help me?

Comment: The notion of migrating PRs makes little sense, as they are not a Git feature. You can migrate the repository with all its commits and branches and tags but that has little to do with the PRs. They are a feature of the remote hosting service, and every individual hosting service (GitHub or Bitbucket or whatever) has its own idiosyncratic way of providing them. So there is nothing to transfer. A particular hosting service might know how to import from another hosting service but if not, you're out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean from one server to another? It was github before but not anymore? Or is this on prem github or github enteprise or something like that?

Comment: I want to transfer between two GitHub enterprise